# String to double with decimal

Tags: string, matlab, double

Say I have a string `s = '128.0'` and I want to convert it to double,

I am trying to use:

```
news = str2double(s);
```

But the value of s is becoming 128. I want the `str2double` function to recognize the decimal point as part of the number.

Any way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: so whats the difference between 128 and 128.0? You could use `format long` to get a different result.

Comment: Agree with @thewaywewalk. Do you wan higher precisions?

Comment: The decimal point is not part of the number. It's part of the string representation of the number in `s`, but once converted to a number it's just a number, it doesn't include formatting.

Comment: Yes it's for precision. Also I would need to convert back to string and the decimal point and 1 figure after it is important!

Comment: transforming it back to string is a completely different thing. You will be able to exactly specify how many digits after the decimal point will be displayed, e.g. by using `spintf`. For calculations in double however, it just doesn't matter.

Comment: yes but that is not my problem, my problem is from string to double. if I have 128.0 in a string, how can I transform it into double and have exactly the same number in double form??

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri Are you suggesting that number 128 is _not_ the same as 128.0?

Comment: In what calculation is it important to distinguish between 128 and 128.0?

Comment: Guys I fixed it when re-converting the double back to string with sprintf like @thewaywewalk suggested. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str2double`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) does what you expect. Type `whos news` or `class(news)` and you'll see the variable `news` is of type `double`:

```
>> class(news)
ans =
double
```

(You could use [`str2num`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) to obtain the same result: `news = str2num(s);` also returns a `double`.)

The fact that you see

```
>> news =
      128
```

without the decimal point is just a matter of *representation*. The number *is* of type `double`, and `128` is of course the same as `128.0`.

Comment: s =

116.0


ans =

char


news =

   116


ans =

double

This is my problem! I need news to be the same as s (with the decimal point) but of type double (so I can use it for calculations)

Comment: That's just _representation_. The number is the same, and _is_ of type `double`. See edited answer